# How to get key & value from Kafka RecordHeaders

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a `ProducerRecord` object.

```
ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> hdr = addHeader.addMDGHeader(record);
```

I'm trying to write a test that checks a particular header key exists.

If I print `hdr.headers().toString()` I get the following `RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = mdpHeader, value = [123, 34, 83, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 78, 111, 34, 58, 48, 44, 34, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 115, 34, 58, 91, 93, 125])], isReadOnly = false)`.

How do I pull out `mdpHeader`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Header.value()](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/header/Header.html#value--) method returns byte array `byte[]`, and then you can convert it into string, you can see more examples [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/)

```
String value = new String(header.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I did this. Is it what you're referring to?

`
for (Header header : hdr.headers()) {
    assertEquals("mdpHeader", header.key());
 }
`

Comment: Are you looking for key or value? @runnerpaul

Comment: I was looking for the key but will also need the value so that answer was helpful.

Comment: No. That's helpful.